# How To Monitor A MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a small application that connects to a MySQL database.  It is very straight forward - basically the database contains alert entries (so as alerts happen, a new record gets written to this database table).  The application has a Datagridview that is bound to this table to populate visually all of the alerts.

However, what I want to achieve is to somehow 'watch' this MySQL table and auto populate the datagridview when new entries are made into this table (or changes).  I also want to be able to notify the user that the datagridview has been updated.

I have populated my datagridview with the MySQL table, but was after some help in setting this up to be an automatic watcher of the table.  I can set everything up in a background worker, but not sure how to find out when data has changed.

Thanks

Comment: [Monitor New Data in MySQL Table using VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38779607/1070452)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MySQL, but you will probably end up having to poll the database to do this. You'll probably end up with some timer based code that will go check the database at a particular interval.

However, you can do your best to minimize the amount of work done on each check. A bad way to do this would be to retrieve the whole table each time and run a whole bunch of checks and comparisons in the program.

Instead, you could use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) (and here's the [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to create one) to know when a row was updated or inserted. How you use the triggers is up to you.

One alternative would be to have a timestamp column on the table that automatically updates whenever there's an insert or update. Similarly you could have a separate table with just the primary key and the same timestamp column (if you don't want to clutter up your main table with extra columns).

Either way, you would keep track of the timestamp you last checked at, and find everything that was inserted or updated after that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add Insert, Update, Delete triggers to the table to log row in a new table with two columns..

1. uid of row changed
2. type of change insert/update/delete

Then you access this table and it tells you the specifically which rows were inserted, updated, deleted