# Monitor New Data in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I want to know if there's new row in my table. How can I do that in **VB.Net** ?

> Example An `Insert Query` has triggered then a `MessageBox` will
>   prompt telling me that there's new data inserted in my table.

If its possible can someone explain and tell me how can I do it? (**It would be better if there is code :3**)

Comment: Store the value of last identity of your table in a variable. Then from a timer, query the identity of your table and compare it with the one stored in your variable. If they are nbot equal then a new data was inserted. You could also retrieve all identities that are higher than the value in your variable to get all rows that were inserted.

Comment: so every seconds the last identity that I'm gonna store in a variable will be triggered and make a condition to it. seems good gonna that logic. Thanks @F0r3v3r-A-N00b

Comment: Which Engine are you using?  InnoDB and MyISAM are the most common but there are others. There are ways to quickly detect changes (not just inserts) but it depends on the Engine.

Comment: @Plutonix Im using both InnoDB and MyISAM Engine :) if there are can you share it to me ? XD

Comment: Detecting changes are simple, but if you are **only** interested in INSERTS it is more involved.  Also what version of MySQL (a few features are version dependant).

Comment: I want to detect the Changes in my table it would be better if a `sub` would return a `boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question remains unclear.  Monitoring only one type of change - "new data" (INSERT) as per the title - is more complicated than detecting **any change** (as per `I want to detect the Changes in my table` in comments which is simpler).

`MySql` provides the means to get the checksum of a table:

```
checksum table TABLE_NAME [QUICK | EXTENDED]
```

MySQL Workbench results for an InnoDB and MyISAM table:

[image]

By watching for changes in those return values, you can detect any change.  But note:

- The table must have been created with the `Checksum = 1` option
- The `QUICK` option does not work on InnoDB tables prior to version 5.7.2 (IIRC and the current Community version is 5.7.14).

Luckily, if you do not specify an option, MySQL seems to pick the fastest one which will return a value.  So, it becomes easy to track changes by table on a Timer:

```vb
' Track last checksum by table
Friend Class TableItem
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property CheckSum As Int64

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        Name = n
        CheckSum = 0
    End Sub
End Class
' a list of them to track more than one table:
Private Tables As List(Of TableItem)
```

Initialize:

```vb
Timer1.Enabled = True

Tables = New List(Of TableItem)
Tables.Add(New TableItem("Sample"))
Tables.Add(New TableItem("SampleISAM"))
```

The Timer Tick event:

```vb
' Note: cannot use Parameters for table or col names
Dim sql = "CHECKSUM TABLE {0} "

Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(mySQLConnStr)
    dbcon.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon)
        ' loop thru collection, polling one at a time
        For Each tbl As TableItem In Tables
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format(sql, tbl.Name)

            Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If rdr.Read Then
                    Dim thisResult = rdr.GetInt64(1)

                    ' ignore the first result
                    If tbl.CheckSum = 0 Then
                        tbl.CheckSum = thisResult
                        Return
                    End If
                    ' save the last non-zed value
                    If tbl.CheckSum <> thisResult Then
                        tbl.CheckSum = thisResult
                        ' method to do something when changed:
                        TableChanged(tbl.Name)
                    End If

                End If
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

My do something method us just reporting the changes to a listbox:

```vb
Private Sub TableChanged(tbl As String)
    lb.Items.Add(String.Format("Table {0} changed {1}", tbl,
                               DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff")))
End Sub
```

[image]

To actually watch for something like only INSERTS, you'd need to use some sort of log table.  Add a trigger which updates that table with a TimeStamp and maybe action code ("insert", "delete").  Then just check the TimeStamp for changes, perhaps filtering out non-watch actions.

Particularly a version to watch multiple tables or certain change events will work better as a class.  The timer code can be encapsulated and it could raise events for a table changes.

- **MySQL v. 5.6 [13.7.2.3 CHECKSUM TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/checksum-table.html)**