# mysql push notification

Tags: mysql, vb.net, push-notification, visual-studio-2017, mysql-event

Reading that **MySQL** doesn't have similar to `SqlDependency`.

What is the best **snippet** to notify other users if a cell changed?

Most of the current posts suggest pooling as recommended approach but can't find proper code to study for **`VB.NET Winform`** without using third party service such Nub.

What I guess could work is to create a `CRON` job at `http server` to fetch if that cell(s) changed then store a `flag` in a secure file; then rather than keep checking MySQL database on interval; watch that flag on server's file system and continue routine. Still this approach doesn't look the proper way.

Comment: MySQL has the means to return the checksum for a table very, very quickly.  It wont be a *snippet*, but more likely a class to watch one or more tables (not "cells") and raise an event when one changes.

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix, any reference please?

Comment: [Monitor changes to data in MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806866)